# Jquery delete record

Tags: jquery, mysql

I had try deleting record with this jquery code:

```
$('#button_erase').click(function() {
    url: 'connection.php?query=delete from table' // ???
}
```

In `connection.php` I had set my connection on db.

But I can't erase record in my table.

Comment: 1) Jquery can't delete records since it isn't even running on the same machine as your DB. 2) You haven't provided nearly enough information to even begin to help you. What does your PHP code look like?

Comment: This is a SQL injection waiting to happen.

Comment: As Justice points out, If this code DID work, your database will be conveniently deleted for you in 10 seconds by any hacker without any real effort.

Comment: Correction. The hacker wouldn't need to delete your entire database. You just did it yourself by omitting the where clause in that statement.

Comment: @JohnFx, chances are he's concatenating it somewhere down the line.

Comment: I doubt it based on what I've seen so far of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#button_erase').click(function() {
    // use post to tap your server
    $.post('connection.php?query=delete from table');
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Passing even part of an SQL query in the URL's query string pretty much means SQL injection will happen in your very close future.

Comment: True, but thats a problem with connection.php and the way it works.

Comment: Sounds like a good reason to never ever use connection.php

Comment: @JohnFx could not agree more. But is such a rookie security problem, that this OP is probably still learning; and I support that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var dataString = 'query='+ 'your query'; 
 $('#button_erase').click(function() {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    $.ajax({   
                                        type: "POST",   
                                        url: "connection.php", 
                                        dataType: "text html",
                                        data: dataString,   
                                        success: function() {   

                                        }   
                                    })
                                });
```

Comment: That is exactly what I posted, but not shorthand and more complicated.